When the user clicked like button, iframe with error received
When the user clicked like button, iframe with error received. I would like to use this code:
<div class="fb-like pull-left" data-href="CURRENT_LINK" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false">

When you enter the page, the like button looks ok, but when you click it, nothing happened and an iframe with error shows.
When the user clicked like button, iframe with error received.
